# check if string exists on a json (python)

Tags: python, json

i only need to print something if a certain condition was met, not all of the data

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
for value in data:
    if value['username'] == 'GDjkhp':
        print(value['content'], '\n')
```

the following code gives me a keyerror

Answer (score -1):

try using the get() method:

```
if value.get('username','no_username') == 'GDjkhp':
    print(value.get('content',''), '\n')
```

if you need to  check if a key is in there:

```
if 'content' not in value:
    print('content not in json')
```

Comment: it is printing  nothing  because that value json has no  'content' entry. you  could try ```value.get('content','no_content')```

Comment: this `'no_username'` is not necessary, just omit it - `get` defaults to `None`

Comment: ~~@gog there's a string comparison,  so it would give  error when checking ```None=='GDjkhp'```~~ gog is right

Comment: just try it ;)...

Comment: thanks for taking me in the right direction, the problem was some logic error. data was nested:

```for value in data:
    if value['author']['username'] == 'GDjkhp':
        print(value['content'], '\n')```

Comment: @gog you're right!